# Defining default values in c++ constructor?

Tags: c++

Longtime java programmer here, recently switched to C++ for the first time.

I am trying to have several constructors for a `Person` class. I have defined `Person` as follows:

```
class Person {

private:
//stuff

public:
    Person(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, int age);
    Person();//I want to define a constructor with no parameters, but NOT a default constructor!

};
```

My implementation:

```
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, int age)
    : firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName), age(age)
{
}

Person::Person()//no errors here
    : firstName("default first"), lastName("default last"), age(0)
{
}
```

Finally, my main function:

```
int main() {

    Person p1 = Person("Chuck", "Norris", 55)//Variable constructor
    Person p2 = Person();//SHOULD invoke no-args constructor
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I attempt to instantiate p2 using the no args constructor, I get the following error:

`Expected a ';'`, which in this context makes no sense. I tried `Person p2;`, same issue.

How does one call a no-args constructor in C++ with user-defined default values?

Comment: Well, you're missing a `;` on the first line, after `Person("Chuck", "Norris", 55)`, so it does make sense. As a side note, in C++ there are no distinctions between a "no args" constructor and a default one.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing, whatsoever, with your default constructor's invocation. You forgot to do something on the previous line.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Well, this was nothing short of embarrassing.

Comment: To define default parameters put `=` and an appropriate rvalue constexpr for the last parameters. After one all following parameters must specify default values.

Comment: Concerning that comment "define a constructor with no parameters, but NOT a default constructor" -- a constructor that can be invoked with no arguments **is** a default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `;` after p1!

```
int main() {

    Person p1 = Person("Chuck", "Norris", 55) <-HERE
    Person p2 = Person();//SHOULD invoke no-args constructor
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this was embarassing.